# "local variable 'e' referenced before assignment" what does this error mean? How do I fix this error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying use  *del.icio.us*  API and following the examples from the book **Programming Collective Intelligence**

When I use these commands in python 3.6.2:

>>> from deliciousrec import *

>>> delusers=initializeUserDict('programming')

I get this error:

```
<urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>, 4 tries left.  
<urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>, 3 tries left.  
<urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>, 2 tries left. 
<urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>, 1 tries left.  
Traceback (most recent call last):               
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
   File"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\deliciousrec.py", line 10, in initializeUserDict            
     for p1 in get_popular(tag=tag)[0:count]:   
   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pydelicious-0.6-py3.6.egg\pydelicious\__init__.py", line 1042, in get_popular        
   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pydelicious-0.6-py3.6.egg\pydelicious\__init__.py", line 1026, in getrss    
   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pydelicious-0.6-py3.6.egg\pydelicious\__init__.py", line 455, in dlcs_rss_request      
   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pydelicious-0.6-py3.6.egg\pydelicious\__init__.py", line 239, in http_request                    
   UnboundLocalError: local variable 'e' referenced before assignment
```

I can not open pydelicious-0.6-py3.6.egg and access the init file that is asked to be modified here. 
Has anyone seen this type of error before. How do I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This library's [PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/pydelicious/) is written in the past tense:

> Was a complete Python interface to del.icio.us Bookmarks’ HTTP API’s.

Its home page is a Github repo that says:

> Old pydelicious work (--2010)

The only update since 2010 is:

> [2016] del.icio.us was gone since about 2009, and redirected to delicious.com. At the moment there is another login page back at del.icio.us. Not sure what they're up to now."

Even [the old 2010 page](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pydelicious/) said:

> IMPORTANT: pydelicious has not been updated to use the OAuth protocol. New users with a Yahoo account/email will not be able to use this library.

So, it seems very likely that this library was never updated for Python 3.x, or for up-to-date versions of whichever libraries it depends on, or for whatever the new `del.icio.us` is.

---

But meanwhile, if you want to debug it yourself, you can.

To look at source inside a `.egg` archive, you can either do it from within Python:

```
>>> import deliciousrec
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getsource(deliciousrec)
```

… or you can extract the `.egg` archive using your favorite ZIP-file tool, because that's all `.egg` files are.

… or you can just clone the GitHub repo, or [view it online](https://github.com/bvberkum/python-delicious), which is probably the best solution.

---

As Hamms pointed out in a comment, if you look at [the function that's raising](https://github.com/bvberkum/python-delicious/blob/bc8bd483d3db6a295dcd05b2fc29ba983a423c53/pydelicious/__init__.py#L237), it's doing this:

```
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    # reraise unexpected protocol errors as PyDeliciousException
    raise PyDeliciousException, "%s" % e
```

In Python 2, that meant to handle exceptions of type `urllib2.HTTPError`, and bind `e` to the exception for the rest of the function.

In Python 2.6, this was soft-deprecated in favor of this new syntax:

```
except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
    # reraise unexpected protocol errors as PyDeliciousException
    raise PyDeliciousException, "%s" % e
```

In Python 3, the old syntax went away entirely, so it's now illegal.

The `2to3` tool will automatically fix this particular issue for you, but it may not fix everything; you'll need to manually port the code to 3.x. And of course that may not do any good, since you're trying to call an API that went away in 2010.

Comment: You can even look [specifically at the function that's throwing the error](https://github.com/bvberkum/python-delicious/blob/bc8bd483d3db6a295dcd05b2fc29ba983a423c53/pydelicious/__init__.py#L237) to see that it is using the deprecated `except Exception, e:` syntax instead of the preferred `except Exception as e`. The latter is required for Python 3.x

Comment: Haha, that's the sneaky thing about 1:1 odds

Comment: I suspect either the OP is using 2.7, or that repository isn't representative of the module that OP actually downloaded. Because if he was running that code in 3.X, I'd expect a SyntaxError, rather than an UnboundLocal error.

Comment: @Kevin If `setuptools` managed to build an egg named `pydelicious-0.6-py3.6.egg` and install it into a directory named `Python36` while using Python 2.7, the OP must have much bigger problems that that… So I suspect it's the second option. Maybe the OP found some incomplete port to 3.x that someone started but then abandoned or something.

Comment: _"Maybe the OP found some incomplete port to 3.x"_. Quite possibly. For instance, the third google hit for "pydelicious" is https://gist.github.com/takashi/2967f9c5ec8ebab5f622, which uses `except urllib.error.HTTPError as e` syntax for that function.

Comment: @Kevin Also, the current tree is versioned `0.6.2-dev`, and the OP has 0.6.0, so apparently someone forked it before even 0.6.1… but the one you found was forked from even earlier, 0.5.0, so presumably not that one… At any rate, trying to chase down which broken version of this dead library the OP has is probably not very profitable.